# Sustituir una numeración en strings de Python

Tags: python

¿Cómo podría hacer una secuencia para sustituir los dos últimos número antes del .png?

Tengo estos archivos de:

```
imagen_01_0000.png
...
imagen_01_0023.png
```

La idea es sustituir el 0000 por 0001, 0002, 0003, hasta 0023.

Lo tengo medio hecho con un for, pero no consigo sustituir más de un dígito:

```
for i in range(24):
     nombre_archivo = 'imagen_01_000{}.png'.format(x)
```

Así, obtengo hasta el número 9 correctamente y después me devuelve un dígito más de la cuenta:

```
img_01_0000.png
img_01_0001.png
img_01_0002.png
img_01_0003.png
img_01_0004.png
img_01_0005.png
img_01_0006.png
img_01_0007.png
img_01_0008.png
img_01_0009.png
```

aquí, ya lo hace mal:

```
img_01_00010.png
```

Esteré muy agradecido si alguien me ayuda con esto, además, me ayudará a aplicarlo a otras cadenas en el futuro. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: no entiendo cuál es el problema. ¿Podrías dar un [mcve] indicando claramente qué tienes, qué querrías y qué falla?

Comment: `'imagen_01_{:04d}.png'.format(i)`, o si usas Python 3.7 o superior: `f'imagen_01_{i:04d}.png'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifica la linea

```
nombre_archivo = 'imagen_01_00{:02d}.png'.format(i)
```